# Image Upload While Registration Magento

Tags: php, magento

I have a custom registration form integrated to CMS page through which if user create an account he will be assigned a special customer group. 
I want to create an image upload form through which a customer can upload his identity card picture while registering through that form.

That picture will be stored in Media/Customer directory or send through Email as an attachment.

I'm new so complete guide will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

1-put below code to your form

```
<input type="file" name="customerimg"  value="" />
```

2- in your controller  in post action put below code

```
public function postAction()
{        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    if ( $post ) {
     if (isset($_FILES)){
            if ($_FILES['customerimg']['name']) {
                    $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . Customer . DS;
                    $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('customerimg');
                    $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','png','gif'));
                    $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
                    $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
                    $destFile = $path.$_FILES['customerimg']['name'];
                    $filename = $uploader->getNewFileName($destFile);
                    $uploader->save($path, $filename);

            }
        }

    $model = Mage::getModel('yourmodel')->setData($post);
    $model->save();

    $mail = new Zend_Mail('utf-8');

$recipients = array(
    Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_custom1/name') => Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_custom1/email'),
    Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_custom2/name') => Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_custom2/email'),
);
$mailBody   = "<b>Error Code: </b>" . $errorCod . "<br />
";
$mailBody .= "<b>Error Massage: </b>" . $errorMsg . "<br />
";
$mail->setBodyHtml($mailBody)
    ->setSubject('Lorem Ipsum')
    ->addTo($recipients)
    ->setFrom(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email'), "FromName");


    //file content is attached
$file       = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . Customer . DS . $filename;
$attachment = file_get_contents($file);
$mail->createAttachment(
    $attachment,
    Zend_Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
    Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
    Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
    'attachment_1.log'
);

try {
    $mail->send();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::logException($e);
}

}
}
```

Comment: Dear, It seems promising but I'm but confuse about in which controller do I exactly have to write that code and somewhere on google I've read that  form enctype should be multipart/form-data.

Comment: in form action you need to assign your custom module action like <form action="<?php $this->getUrl('mymodule/controller/action');?>"> in your module have controller. please refer http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/magento-custom-module-development--cms-20643